# Thread safety issues in reference assignment using method call

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following code:

```
class SomeClass {
    private Map<String, String> someMap = null;

    public String getValue(String key) {
        if (someMap == null) {
            someMap = initialize(); // initialize() is some method which returns a proper map.
        }
        return someMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

Assuming I don't care about `someMap` getting initialized more than once, are there any other thread-safety issues that I need to be concerned about here.

As per [what-operations-in-java-are-considered-atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4756578/715769) , Reference assignment is certainly atmoic. Is the assignment to `someMap` guaranteed to happen after the method call to `initialize()` (seems logical to me). Is there any possibility that a thread can see a partially constructed `someMap`. Does it matter if instead of a map, I have some other type of object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is **not** thread-safe. If two threads invoke the method `getValue` on the same object, it is possible, that one thread sees a partially created `someMap`.

In order to avoid this problem, you have to remove the data races. The simplest solution is to declare `someMap` as `volatile`. The simple rule to remember is: If the code contains no data races, then all executions will appear to be sequentially consistent.

Comment: I don't understand this. Wouldn't the assignment to `someMap` happen after `initialize` returns, as the last operation inside the `if` block. Given that reference assignment is atmoic, how can the map assigned to `someMap` be partially created.

Comment: @Vivek: If we are talking only about one thread, then it's true that the assignment to `someMap` happens after `initialize` returns. However, if we talk about several threads, that's only true if the execution is _sequentially consistent_. Take a look at the Wikipedia article on [Sequential Consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_consistency).

Comment: Thanks, got it now. If I remember correctly, making the variable volatile forces all the local writes to be flushed to the main memory before the assignment to the variable.

Comment: @Vivek: You are only writing once (or a few times). The overhead for write operations shouldn't matter, and the overhead for _volatile reads_ is low.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a Thread Safe even if you put volatile because if two threads are called getValue method at a same time, the following scenario can happen

1) **Thread 1 & Thread 2**  check *if (someMap == null)* , both will pass and try to reinitialise.

2) Both will reinitialize the reference. Thread 1 return the old reference which one is override by thread 2 .

3) So please refer the link [Double Checked Locking in Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093735/double-checked-locking-in-singleton)

Comment: As i mentioned in the question, I don't care about someMap being initialized multiple times. So your scenario does not apply.