# java codes that fails double locking checking

Tags: java, concurrency, singleton, double-checked-locking

**Notes:** I know that before java 5(given in 2004), double checking lock will fail in java, even you add "volatile" to the "instance" field. and after java 5 the volatile semantics has been right for double checking lock. I also know that [without "volatile", double checking lock will fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-double-checked-locking) even after java5, due to out-of-order executing. BUT, **My question is : how to write codes to prove that(double checking lock will fail without "volatile")???**

I have read lots of articles saying that double checking lock will fail in java, so I think below codes, which try to get a singleton instance of SocketFactory, will fail ( since the "instance" field is not volatile)：

```
  private static SocketFactory instance  = null;
  private static SocketFactory getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) {
         synchronized (SocketFactory.class){
            if (instance == null){
               instance = new SocketFactory(); // line 1
            }
         }
      }
      return instance;
   }
```

but, the question is , if above code will fail, how can I prove that? I tried to write below codes( I thought, if the line 1 will be re-ordered, the "instance" reference may pointing to a SocketFactory object with the "constructed" field being "false"):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class TIJ_doubleCheckingLock {

    static TIJ_doubleCheckingLock instance;

    private Object lock;

    private boolean constructed = false;

    {   
        constructed = false;
    }

    private TIJ_doubleCheckingLock() {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
        constructed = true;
    }

    static TIJ_doubleCheckingLock getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (TIJ_doubleCheckingLock.class) {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(Exception e) {

                }
                if(instance == null) {
                    instance = new TIJ_doubleCheckingLock();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        class MyThread extends Thread {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    TIJ_doubleCheckingLock instance = TIJ_doubleCheckingLock.getInstance();
                    String fileName = "TIJ_doubleCheckingLockResult.txt";
                    java.io.File file = new File(fileName);
                    try {
                        if(!instance.constructed) {
                            java.nio.file.Files.write(Paths.get(file.toURI()), (instance.constructed+"").
                                    getBytes("utf-8"), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }

        }

        Thread firstThread = new MyThread();
        firstThread.start();

        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch(Exception e) {}


        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            Thread thread = new MyThread(); 
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

but I　never see a "false" in the txt file. 
so how can I prove that the double checking lock will fail?

Comment: You shouldn't be reading articles from the 90's.

Comment: you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093735/double-checked-locking-in-singleton

Comment: @ Kayaman so you mean that the double checking lock will NOT fail, without any volatile??

Comment: No, I mean your opening statement of `double checking lock will fail in java` was true in the 90's. I remember those times. You still need the `volatile` keyword to make sure that multiple threads will see the correct value.

Comment: @Kayaman I know that before java 5(given in 2004), double checking lock will fail in java, even you add "volatile" to the "instance" field. and after java 5 the volatile semantics has been right for double checking lock.  I also know that without "volatile", double checking lock will fail even after java5, due to out-of-order executing. **BUT, My question is : how to write codes to prove that(double checking lock will fail without "volatile")???**

Comment: Well, your example won't work. You'd need to run it a few million times at least. I believe this is a bit beyond your skills and I'm too busy to write you an example. Let's hope someone who has the time does it for you.

Comment: so everyone is saying that, but no one can really prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double checked locking [was broken in Java](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html). Your code works fine with Java 5 and onwards. The JVM since got a [new memory model](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/).

Also your code needs the `volatile` keyword.

```
private static volatile SocketFactory instance;
```

Comment: then, what's the difference with or without the volatile keyword?

Comment: volatile guarantees that every thread reads the same value and does not cache it. Without it your double checked login might fail.

Comment: @ raupach  you can see that in my codes there is no volatile used. so my code might fail, right? but the question is : how to prove that my code might fail ?

Comment: If SocketFactory is immutable your code works, otherwise there is chance your code breaks.

Comment: That is the problem with multi-threaded applications. Hard to spot the problem. Why don't you read the articles first?

Comment: yes I have read lots of articles. but without any code really can prove that the double checking lock will fail.

Answer (score -1):

you need to know the difference of my code in synchronized:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

/**
 * @author heyunxia (love3400wind@163.com)
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 2016-01-15 下午3:50
 */
public class SocketFactoryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SocketFactoryTest test = new SocketFactoryTest();
        test.run();

    }

    private static final int COUNTER = 20;

    CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(COUNTER);

    public void run(){
        for(int i=0; i<COUNTER; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    SocketFactory.getInstance(barrier);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

}


class SocketFactory {
    private static SocketFactory instance = null;

    public static SocketFactory getInstance(CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        if (instance == null) {
            try {
                barrier.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (SocketFactory.class) {
                // option 1
                instance = new SocketFactory();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "***");

                /*
                // option 2
                if (instance == null) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "***");
                    instance = new SocketFactory();
                }else {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-have already instanced...");
                }*/
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```