# Java synchronized with double if condition

Tags: java, synchronized

New to Java from C++ and came across this synchronized block example (more context on this [page](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html)). My question is:
<strike>Shouldn't the "if" statement also be included in the "synchronized block"? Or else other threads could be executing the same piece of code, pass the "if" checkpoint and thought that the "_instance" is null and then after the current thread finishes executing the synchronized block (and creates a new instance), other thread(s) will create duplicated instances? Thanks!</strike>

Now I realized that the code was actually doing double-checking, I have a new question then, why is double-checking needed? Thanks!
The code block is copied below:

```
public class Singleton{ 
private static volatile Singleton _instance; 
public static Singleton getInstance(){
    if(_instance == null){ //Shouldn't this line be included in the synchronized block?
        synchronized(Singleton.class){
            if(_instance == null) _instance = new Singleton(); 
        }
    } 
    return _instance; 
}
```

Comment: This is a poor approach for creating a lazy singleton. The [initialization on demand idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) is far cleaner.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855700/why-is-volatile-used-in-this-example-of-double-checked-locking

Comment: If you have a new question, pose it in a separate question.  But before you do so, you should try performing your own research.  Now that you have a name for what you're looking at, that shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 1):

If you include the statement `_instance == null` inside the `synchronized` block it will add **unnecessary overhead** (getting lock and realising the lock) for each request/call made to the `getInstance()` method i.e., you will only acquire/release the lock (on the **Singleton** object) only when you know that the object has not been created, so there is no need to unnecessarily get the lock and check if it is not `null` already.

> Why is double-checking needed?

Assume that you are doing the check only once like below:

```
public static Singleton getInstance(){
    synchronized(Singleton.class){
         if(_instance == null) //SINGLE IF CHECK
            _instance = new Singleton(); 
    }
    return _instance; 
}
```

Now the issue is that the code will need to **acquire/release the lock (on the `Singleton` class) for each call** made to the method, which is not required because once the `Singleton` instance (using new `Singleton()`) has been created during the first call to the method, it is **`_instance` is not going to be `null`**. So, by adding the additional condition  `_instance == null` above `synchronized`, it will avoid the unnecessary locking overhead for each call afterward, this concept is well known as **double-checked locking**.

I suggest you also read [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom) (text copied below, emphasis mine) and also read duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093735/double-checked-locking-in-singleton) to understand this concept better.

> The double-checked locking idiom is a software design pattern used to
>   reduce the overhead of acquiring a lock by first testing the locking
>   criterion without actually acquiring the lock. **Double-checked locking
>   improves performance by limiting synchronization** to the rare case of
>   computing the field's value or constructing a new instance for the
>   field to reference and by foregoing synchronization during the common
>   case of retrieving an already-created instance or value.

Comment: @efekctive and for good reason. I suggest you read the duplicate too, as you clearly don't understand the DCL idiom.