# What are 'real' and 'synthetic' Method parameters in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

Looking into `j.l.r.Executable` class I've found a method called `hasRealParameterData()` and from its name and code context I assume that it tells whether a particular method has 'real' or 'synthetic' params.

If I take e.g. method `Object.wait(long, int)` and call `hasRealParameterData()` it turns out that it returns `false` which is confusing to me, as the method is declared in `Object` class along with its params.

From this I've got a couple of questions:

1. What are 'real' and 'synthetic' Method parameters and why Java believes that params of `Object.wait(long, int)` are not 'real'?
2. How can I define a method with 'real' params?

Comment: j.l.r.Executable does not have a method called `hasRealParameterData()`. At least, not a public one. It's an implementation detail and not meant for you to consume. What with the restrictions on reflection in java9 and being aggressively applied in later versions, you can't even if you wanted to.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do? This question boils down to: "I called this undocumented __private__ method and I do not understand what it returns", which is a weird question to ask. Whatever problem you ran into that made you think: "I know! I'll call this package private method! Oh, but I'm not sure why it returns what it is returning, I better go ask on SO" - That was not a good solution to the underlying problem. Please explain the underlying problem.

Comment: From a first look, I can already tell you that this method has nothing to do with synthetic or non-synthetic parameters. But why bother, I agree with @rzwitserloot What do you hope from making guesswork about an implementation specific, non-public method and then trying to make that method return a particular result value when you don’t even know its actual purpose?

Comment: @rzwitserloot I'm just trying to figure out what is the method for and how it works. Plain curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

### Preamble - don't do this.

As I mentioned in the comments as well: This is a package private method. That means:

[A] It can change at *any* time, and code built based on assuming it is there will need continuous monitoring; any new java release means you may have to change things. You probably also need a framework if you want your code to be capable of running on multiple different VM versions. Maybe it'll never meaningfully change, but **you have no guarantee** so you're on the hook to investigate each and every JVM version released from here on out.

[B] It's undocumented by design. It may return weird things.

[C] The java module system restriction stuff is getting tighter every release; calling this method is hard, and will become harder over time.

Whatever made you think this method is the solution to some problem you're having - unlikely. If it does what you want at all, there are probably significantly better solutions available. I strongly advise you take one step backwards and ask a question about the problem you're trying to solve, instead of asking questions about this particular solution you've come up with.

Having gotten that out of the way...

### Two different meanings

The problem here is that 'synthetic' means two utterly unrelated things and the docs are interchanging the meaning. The 4 unrelated meanings here are:

- `SYNTHETIC`, the JVM flag. This term is in the JLS.
- 'real', a slang term used to indicate anything that is not marked with the JVM SYNTETHIC flag. This term is, as far as I know, not official. There isn't an official term other than simply 'not SYNTHETIC'.
- Synthetic, as in, the parameter name (and other data not guaranteed to be available in class files) are synthesised.
- Real, as in, not the previous bullet point's synthetic. The parameter is fully formed solely on the basis of what the class file contains.

The 'real' in hasRealParameterData is referring to the 4th bullet, not the second. But, all 4 bullet point meanings are used in various comments in the Executable.java source file!

### The official meaning - the `SYNTHETIC` flag

The JVM has the notion of the synthetic flag.

This means it wasn't in the source code but `javac` had to make this element in order to make stuff work. This is done to paper over mismatches between java-the-language and java-the-VM-definition, as in, differences between `.java` and `.class`. Trivial example: At least until the nestmates concept, the notion of 'an inner class' simply **does not exist** at the class file level. There is simply no such thing. Instead, `javac` fakes it: It turns:

```
class Outer {
  private static int foo() {
    return 5;
  }

  class Inner {
    void example() {
      Outer.foo();
    }
  }
}
```

Into 2 seemingly unrelated classes, one named `Outer`, and one named `Outer$Inner`, literally like that. You can trivially observe this: Compile the above file and look at that - 2 class files, not one.

This leaves one problem: The JLS claims that inner classes get to call `private` members from their outer class. However, at the JVMS (class file) level, we turned these 2 classes into separate things, and thus, `Outer$Inner` cannot call `foo`. Now what? Well, `javac` generates a 'bridger' method. It basically compiles this instead:

```
class Outer {
  private static int foo() {
    return 5;
  }

  /* synthetic */ static int foo$() {
    return foo();
  }
}

class Outer$Inner {
  private /* synthetic */ Outer enclosingInstance;

  void example() {
    Outer.foo$();
  }
}
```

The JVM can generate fields, extra overload methods (for example, if you write `class MyClass implements List<String> {}`, you will write e.g. `add(String x)`, but `.add(Object x)` still needs to exist to cater to erasure - that method is generated by `javac`, and will be marked with the SYNTHETIC modifier.

One effect of the SYNTHETIC modifier is that `javac` acts as if these methods do not exist. If you attempt to actually write `Outer.foo$()` in java code, it won't compile, javac will act as if the method does not exist. Even though it does. If you use bytebuddy or a hex editor to clear that flag in the class file, then javac will compile that code just fine.

### generating parameter names

Weirdly, perhaps, in the original v1.0 Java Language Spec, parameter **types** were, obviously, a required part of a method's signature and are naturally encoded in class files. You can write this code:  `Integer.class.getMethods();`, loop through until you find the static `parseInt` method, and then ask the `j.l.r.Method`  instance about its parameter type, which will dutifully report: the first param's type is `String`. You can even ask it for its annotations.

**But weirdly enough as per JLS 1.0 you cannot ask for its name** - simply because **it is not there**, there was no actual need to know it, it does take up space, java wanted to be installed on tiny devices (I'm just guessing at the reasons here), so the info is not there. You can add it - as debug info, via the `-g` parameter, because having the names of things is convenient.

However, in later days this was deemed too annoying, and more recently compilers *DO* stuff the param name in a class file. Even if you do not use the `-g` param to 'include debug symbol info'.

Which leaves one final question: java17 can still load classes produced by `javac 1.1`. So what is it supposed to do when you ask for the name of param1 of such a method? The name simply cannot be figured out, it simply isn't there in the class file. It can fall back to looking at the debug symbol table (and it does), but if that isn't there - then you're just out of luck.

What the JVM does is make that name `arg0`, `arg1`, etc. You may have seen this in decompiler outputs.

**THAT** is what the `hasRealParameterData()` method is referring to as 'real' - `arg0` is 'synthesized', and in contrast, `foo` (the actual name of the param) is 'real'.

So how would one have a method that has 'real' data in that sense (the 4th bullet)? Simply compile it, it's quite hard to convince a modern java compiler to strip all param names. Some obfuscators do this. You can compile with a really old `-target` and definitely don't add `-g`, and you'll probably get non-real, as per `hasRealParameterData()`.

Comment: sorry, but I don't get expected result: I take a method with at least one param, compile enclosing class with `-g:vars` and it makes no difference.

Comment: I see the param names appearing in Local Variables table, but If I take the method and at debug time execute `hasRealParameterData()` it returns `false` and if I introspect `parameters` array then I see `int arg0` instead of `int param`.

Comment: Then you're compiling it in a way that you aren't preserving param names. I can't reproduce, using `javac` from OpenJDK17, this behaviour. You're introspecting reflective calls about _your own stuff_ right, no `Object.wait`? Perhaps edit your answer and include some code and the commands you run (e.g. `javac -version` gives this, I run `javac -g:vars That`, then I run this code and it gives me `arg0` - why).

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. `-g:vars` tells the compiler to retain local variable information in a dedicated [debug attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13). Java 8 introduced a [different attribute solely for parameter information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.24) which is included only when `-parameters` has been specified when compiling (but always for canonical `record` constructors). `Executable.getParameters()` does not use the debug information but only the dedicated parameter information.