# methods in a singleton class are thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm designing a custom logging framework for our application.

I'm reading [*Patterns For Logging Diagnostic Messages*](ftp://ftp.ma.utexas.edu/pub/papers/alec/Harrison.ps.gz), which is being used in http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html

On page 3 it says:

> Because it is a Singleton, it easily preserves the order of the messages.

I think, for example, given Singleton class S, if a class B is trying to acquire the instance of S while a class A already got the instance S, then B cannot acquire the instance of S since A already got the instance of S.

That's why the order of message is preserved based on my understanding.

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. How the class B knows that class A is done with the class S and no longer needs it so that B can acquire S?
3. if my understanding is correct and if Singleton class S has some methods: test1() and test2() as you see below.

Are test1() and test2() are thread-safe?

These methods will be called outside of class S, something like

`S.getInstance().test1("message")`

in class A or class B for example.

Which means when class A and class B are trying to write some data in a log file by calling test1(), this data will be written in the order of acquiring the instance of S?

If not, to make methods thread-safe in a Singleton class S, should I also use `synchronized` keyword on methods test1() and test2() or `lock` for these methods?

```
public class S {                  // singleton class S

    private static S instance;

    private S(){}

    public static S getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new S();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void test1(String log) {
       // writing some data to a log file
    }

    public static void test2(String log) {
       // writing some data to a log file
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you show here is definitely not thread safe.  I'll try to parse your text a bit more but you should look up some thread safe patterns in Java.

Comment: Re.: `B cannot acquire the instance of S` no false.  Singletons are inherently shared between classes, *every* class acquires the same instance of a singleton, and your code does nothing to prevent this.

Comment: I think there are just too many misconceptions above to continue.  Please get a copy of *Java Concurrency in Practice* http://jcip.net/ and read up on how thread safety works.  One won't ever produce correct code just by taking random guesses.

Comment: @user2761895, any finding on the question. Are test1() and test2() accessed by a thread at a time as they are instance method and only single instance available to access them?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not thread-safe. Suppose for instance  I had two threads T1, and T2, and S had property foo. Suppose T1 and T2 are modifying the value of foo, and then using the value of foo to perform some other operation.

Then, I could presumably have T1 access S.getInstance, check the getInstance is not set, and at the same time, T2 can access S.getInstance and see that the instance is not set. T1, could then potentially set the instance, but since T2 had also at the same time detected that the instance was not set, would also set the instance for S. Therefore, the value of S.instance, is going to actually be the one set by T2. In otherwords, there is a race condition between T1 and T2 to see who can set the instance of S first.

To make this synchronous, you should definitely have the getInstance method be synchronized so only one thread could be acting on it at once. Also, you should probably make the instance of S volatile so as to ensure that any thread that is accessing the instance of S is always going to be working with the "latest" copy.  (because presumably one thread could be doing some other read operation on that instance while it's being modified).

i.e. something like this:

```
public class S {                  // singleton class S

    private volatile static S instance;

    private S(){}

    public synchronized static S getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new S();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void test1(String log) {
       // writing some data to a log file
    }

    public static void test2(String log) {
       // writing some data to a log file
    }
}
```

Also, here's a good link on why you should use volatile:

[What is the point of making the singleton instance volatile while using double lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639746/what-is-the-point-of-making-the-singleton-instance-volatile-while-using-double-l)

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example is not thread safe. If two concurrent threads try to get the singleton object at the same time, there is a chance each thread creates an object. You should use `synchronized` keyword on the `getInstance` method to avoid this behavior.

You also have to mark as `synchronized` every instance method (not static) on the singleton class that access data from the object (non-static properties). This way, two different methods will never run concurrently, preventing the data from being messed up.

In your example, you don't need to use `synchronized` on `test1` and `test2` as long as the methods they call from the instance are all `synchronized`.

Your `S` class should probably look like this

```
public class S {

    private static S instance;

    private S() {}

    public synchronized static S getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new S();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized doSomething() {
        // Code that uses data from instance
    }

    public static void test1(String log) {
        // ...
        S.getInstance().doSomthing();
        // ...
    }

    public static void test2(String log) {
        // ...
        S.getInstance().doSomthing();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You are telling to use `synchronized` in places that dont necessary need to be. Without knowing the implementation of `test1()` and `test2()` we cannot assume if they need any kind of locking at all. Also `getInstance()` can be rewritten without full synchronization on the class and be less expensive.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code sample above is not a safe singleton. There are possibility of race conditions at static method `getInstance`. If 2 or more threads run `if(instance==null)` at the same time, more than one *S* instances will be constructed. To correct this use *eager-initialization* by providing a static final field of your class instance.

Example:-

```
public class S{

     private static final S INSTANCE = new S();

     private S(){}

     public static S getInstance(){
         return INSTANCE;
     }

     public void doSomething(){
         //the rest of the code
     }
}
```

Even better since JDK 5, use *enum* type to represent safe singleton. It also provide guards against serialization attack for free.

Example:-

```
public enum Singleton {

    S;

    public void doSomething(){/*...*/}
}
```

Secondly, if `doSomething` does not modify *S* instance state or it is a stateless object, then it is thread-safe. Otherwise have to provide synchronization guards to preserve its state correctness in multi-threaded environment.

**Note**: In the past, many naive implementations of double locking idiom to solve lazy-loading singleton without synchronization were fraught with perils. Refer to good article below signed by Doug Lee, Joshua Bloch & et al. for further read.

[The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)

Answer (score -1):

To answer your questions:

1. No, your understanding is incorrect.
2. By using some sort of locking mechanism, such as a `Semaphore`.
3. That depends entirely on what's inside those methods. If they only use variables that are local to the method (i.e. those that are on the stack and not in the heap) that the method is probably thread-safe. If you need to access to variables that are local to the class, such as a log file, you again need a locking mechanism.

Just to add, you cannot have a static `getInstance` method and expect it to be thread-safe. The best way to accomplish this is to have code as follows:

```
private final static S INSTANCE = new S();
```

This will only be instantiated the moment you first access it.

Comment: That's not true. If you use `synchronized` on the `getInstance` declaration, the singleton creation is thread-safe. The only difference from this and your static initialization is the `getInstance` method will lazily initialize the object, while your code will eagerly initialize the object as soon as the class is loaded.

Comment: Yes, but you'd load the class to get to the `getInstance` method. You won't gain anything by using the `synchronized` keyword. In this particular case, it's the best solution.

Comment: Depending on what you are looking for you gain lazy instantiation by using the synchronized keyword.

Comment: @SeverityOne I'm adding a point that you can't just answer the question saying static methods can't be thread-safe. That is just not true at all. Besides, you can never conclude lazy or eager initialization is better without context.

Comment: But you incur a performance penalty from the `synchronized` keyword. Now this may not be a problem for a logger, which is typically declared as `private final static`... but do you see the similarity? If you're going to use that class, lazy initialisation via `synchronized` doesn't buy you anything. It just complicates code and adds a potential performance hit - in this particular case. Other cases may require different answers, but in this case, lazy initialisation is not the way to go.

Comment: @Leonardo Raele: Also, I think you misread my comment. What I said was "you cannot EXPECT a static method to be thread-safe". Of course you can have thread-safe static methods, but they don't magically become thread-safe just because they're static.

Answer (score -2):

This is not thread safe.  Imagine two competing threads trying to get an instance of S, and both checking at the same time if the instance is null.  In order to lock this for thread safety you will need to use the synchronized keyword.  Try this:

```
public class S {                  // singleton class S

    private static S instance;

    private S(){}

    public static S getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            synchronized (S.class)
            {
                if(instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new S();
                }
            }

        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void test1(String log) {
        // writing some data to a log file
    }

    public static void test2(String log) {
        // writing some data to a log file
    }
}
```

Another option, to avoid the double-checked locking above would be to synchronize the getInstance method like so (although with and added performance hit):

```
public static synchronized S getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new S();
        }

        return instance;
    }
```

Comment: You still have wrong implementation of lazy singleton. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java.