# Getting a Singleton in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have been looking at some Google sample code and they seem to create a singleton using the the following code:

```
companion object {

        // For Singleton instantiation
        @Volatile
        private var instance: CarRepository? = null

        fun getInstance(carDao: CarDao) =
                instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                    instance ?: CarRepository(carDao).also { instance = it }
                }
    }
```

So I know `@Volatile` means that

> Marks the JVM backing field of the annotated property as volatile, meaning that writes to this field are immediately made visible to other threads.

Should all Singletons instances always be marked as `@Volatile`? If so, why?

Lastly, I don't understand the `getInstance` function

```
instance ?: synchronized(this) {
    instance ?: CarRepository(carDao).also { instance = it }
}
```

What is it exactly doing here?

UPDATE:
Source: [Google's Sunflower](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower) 
I changed the Repository and Dao name for my own use, but it is the same logic in the `Repository` files.

Comment: You may want to add a reference to the source code / repository.

Comment: I don't think that this is actually a singleton. See also [Singleton pattern @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Usually you only supply 1 possible instance for a class which isn't affected by a parameter.

Comment: @Roland added source. They marked it as a Singleton, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11640026/321697) for why the field should be volatile. Essentially, without it, it's possible for one thread to get a reference to the instance before it has been fully constructed.

For the `getInstance()` function, you have:

```
instance ?:
```

This means that the method will return `instance` if it's not null, otherwise it will execute the right side of the `?:`.

```
synchronized(this) {
    instance ?:
}
```

Similarly here, after the first check for whether or not the instance is null, after synchronizing on the class (the `companion object`) it again checks for a non-null value and returns it if available, before executing the last command:

```
CarRepository(carDao).also { instance = it }
```

This initializes a new `CarRepository` and then using the `.also` block, assigns `it` (the `CarRepository`) to the `instance` field before returning. It's a bit confusing just because the entire statment is an expression. If you make this much more verbose it might look like:

```
fun getInstance(carDao: CarDao): CarRepository {
    var cachedInstance = instance
    if (cachedInstance != null) {
        return cachedInstance
    }

    synchronized(this) {
        cachedInstance = instance
        if (cachedInstance == null) {
            cachedInstance = CarRepository(carDao)
            instance = cachedInstance
        }
        return cachedInstance
    }
}
```

As a word of warning I'm not really convinced this particular example is a good pattern to follow. For example, consider the following:

```
val carDao1 = CarDaoImpl1()
val carDao2 = CarDaoImpl2()

val carRepo1 = CarRepository.getInstance(carDao1)
val carRepo2 = CarRepository.getInstance(carDao2)

// carRepo2 actually points to carDao1!
```

Comment: thank you! On your warning, when would you need another DAO for Car? The example seems to have a 1:1 relationship between `Dao` and `Repository`. Is there any use case of `@Volatile` outside of singletons?

Comment: The warning is more theoretical, the general issue being the parameter no longer matters after the first initialization which could be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this isn't a real singleton, I will try to explain what's exactly going on with comments:

```
  fun getInstance(carDao: CarDao) =
         /* if the instance is not null, just return it: */
            instance ?: 
         /* instance is null... enter synchronized block for the first thread... 
            all other threads entering here while the first one is still not finished will block then */
            synchronized(this) {
         /* now the next line is actually here for all the blocked threads... as soon as they are released, they should take the instance that was set by the first thread */
                instance ?: 
         /* the next line actually is only executed by the first thread entering the synchronized-block */
                CarRepository(carDao).also { 
                           /* and this sets the instance that finally is returned by all others */
                             instance = it }
            }
```

Regarding the `@Volatile`... well... that's here so that the instance variable actually gets synchronized between the threads then... so that it is available when the first thread returns and the other continue entering the synchronized-block.

Now after the explanation: for a Kotlin way to write singletons check the Kotlin reference regarding [Object Expressions, Object Declarations and Companion Objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations).

Comment: isn't this a `Singleton` it is denoted by `object` as specified in the reference? Could you also clarify what `instance = it`? What does it mean that "sets the instance that finally is returned by all others"?

Comment: Usually a singleton is just get by a method similar to `getInstance()` (note: no parameter influencing the creation of the returned singleton). `instance = it` sets the newly created `CarRepository` to `instance`. And regarding "the others": all other calls to `getInstance` return that instance which is set within the `also`... Clearer now? Or more confused? :-/